# first it occured

Tags: word-order, relative-pronouns, transitivity

I have the problems with using/non-using of the pronoun "it" in seemingly simple sentences like this one:

*First it occured the event A.*

or

*First the event A occured.*

Which one of these sentences is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Subjects precede verbs in English, most of the time.  You also don't want to use a subject pronoun and an explicit subject at the same time.

In your sentence, *the event* is the subject, so you want to say:

> First the event A occurred.

---

*To occur* means *to happen* - it's a <strike>passive</strike> intransitive verb - so it doesn't take an object or any qualification saying something caused the occurrence.  You can't say "X occurred Y" where Y tells how X occurred.

If you want to say something caused event A to occur, then

> First, it caused event A to occur

is better.

Comment: An *intransitive* verb, not a *passive* one.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the preceding sentence, I'd suggest that your problem with pronouns like "it" is that you are not establishing what the pronoun refers to before you use it. (note that my use of "it" came after establishing that its subject was "pronoun").

In your first sentence, "it" apparently means "event A", but the reader has no way of knowing this when "it" is encountered.

There are exceptions (aren't there always?) such as "First, it occurred to me that there was something strange about event A", but I don't think that you're concerned with this.